# Letting Ninject manage my transaction state, practice concerns

Tags: nhibernate, ninject

I'm letting Ninject manage my `ISession` and `ITransaction` state in Fluent nHibnerate with the following registration method - I am wondering if it is sufficient control of transactions, or whether I need to be putting this somewhere else.

The thought is that each `ISession` is created on a request, and that Ninject handles the commit of everything done during that request.

```
public class SessionModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISessionFactory>()
            .ToMethod(c => CreateSessionFactory())
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(c => OpenSession())
            .InRequestScope()
            .OnActivation(session =>
            {
                session.BeginTransaction();
                session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
            })
            .OnDeactivation(session =>
            {
                if (session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        session.Flush();
                        session.Transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        session.Transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new <see cref="NHibernate.ISessionFactory"/> to connect to a database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A constructed and mapped <see cref="NHibernate.ISessionFactory"/>.
    /// </returns>
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            sessionFactory = Persistence.SessionFactory.Map
                (System.Web.Configuration
                    .WebConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["Local"]
                    .ConnectionString
                );
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Open a new <see cref="NHibernate.ISession"/> from a <see cref="NHibernate.ISessionFactory"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A new <see cref="NHibernate.ISession"/>.
    /// </returns>
    private static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        // check to see if we even have a session factory to get a session from
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            CreateSessionFactory();

        // open a new session from the factory if there is no current one
        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

I've examined the runtime using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` to write when things occur, and it **does** look like this is doing what I **wanted** it to do. What I am asking you, the community, is whether this is a **good** practice or not. Here is my understanding.

Countless hours of reading on http://ayende.com/blog/default.aspx has led me to re-evaluate a lot of the way I do session management.

A lot of digging into the nHibernate documentation tells me I need to use `ITransaction` **every single time anything happens with my database**.

Placing the management in an attribute is considered a flaw, since it does not adhere to the above mentioned statement.

Doing `ITransaction` per individual operation is not the correct process, because it would require either (A) my Controllers to have access to the `ISession` or (B) My `IRepository<T>` to have the `ITransaction` logic, which I have been told in previous questions was not a good practice.

Placing my `ITransaction` Management in an `HttpModule` adds un-neccessary overhead, since it gives my HttpContext knowledge of the `ISession` and it means I have to do some kind of injection into the `HttpRequest` (which I can do using `[Inject]`, but it doesn't seem wise)

This has led me to this conclusion.

- Transactions should start when an `ISession` is requested.
- Everything that happens in a **single request** is encapsulated by **one** `ISession`
- When an `ITransaction` is done, it needs to be committed so that the 2nd Level Cache can get its results.

Can anyone shed light on this? Am I finally on the right track? Or have I still missed the point completely?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to hook into `InRequestScope` to start/commit transaction... Thanks for your post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert (and have no experience with ninject), but I do agree with your 3 conclusions, and that's what I do in my projects.
Another thing I can add is that, in my opinion, transactions should be controlled EXPLICITLY and per operation, and not globally (start and beginning of request and commit at the end) like your code suggests.
This is because I believe you want to control your transaction's behaviour- commit or not (or maybe not even start, if no DB access is necessary) for every operation individually.
What I use is a management (or workflow, if you prefer) layer, which is responsible just for that. for example:

```
public class SomeManager : ManagersBase
{
    public void DoSomething(DomainObject obj)
    {
        if (obj.Operation())
        {
            using (ITransaction tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    Session.Update(obj);
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                catch (MeaningfulException ex)
                {
                    //handle
                    tx.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: I am sorry for not accepting this sooner. I thought I had taken care of it. Thank you very much.