# How to rollback nHibernate transaction when an exception occurs during request having Ninject for managing sessions?

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, ninject, rollback

I use nHibernate for ORM and Ninject for IoC. 
I create nHibernate sessions per some custom scope (which you can assume is per request).
I begin the transaction onActivation.
I commit the transaction onDeactivation.

The problem is that if an exception happens during the request I want to rollback the transaction rather than committing it. Any idea how to detect (in a clean way, most probably using Ninject Context) that an exception has happened?

Note: I am not concerned about the exceptions that can happen on commit which I can catch in the following code and role back easily.

```
protected void BindWithSessionWrapper<T>(Func<IContext, T> creationFunc) where T : ISessionWrapper
{
    Bind<T>().ToMethod(creationFunc)
        .InScope(x => new NinjectCustomScope()) // work in progress !!!
        .OnActivation(t => t.Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        .OnDeactivation((c, t) => 
            { 
                t.Session.Transaction.Commit();
                t.Session.Dispose();
            });
}
```

**Update:**

I followed the suggestion by @BatteryBackupUnit. 
So I added the following to the Error EventHandler:

```
    Error += (s, e) =>
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items["ErrorRaised"] = true;
        };
```

And I modified the OnDeactivation to look like this:

```
OnDeactivation(t => 
                    { 
                        if ((bool?)HttpContext.Current.Items["ErrorRaised"] == true)
                            t.Session.Transaction.Rollback();
                        else
                            t.Session.Transaction.Commit();

                        t.Session.Dispose();
                    });
```

It works fine, but that would be better if Ninject would take care of this by setting a flag in the Context if an exception happened :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about implementing an `IHTTPModule` and subscribing to the `Error` event?
Like described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx)

In the `Error` event handler, use `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (ISession))` to retrieve the current session and rollback the transaction.

Note, however, that in case the request did not use a session, this will create one, which is quite superfluous.

You might do something like checking whether a transaction was started and only then rolling it back. But you'd still create a session unnecessarily.

You could further improve that by using the `Error` event handler to set a flag on `HttpContext.Current.Items`, like

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["RollbackTransaction"] = true;
```

and then use it in the `OnDeactivation` of the session like:

```
    .OnDeactivation((c, t) => 
        { 
            if(HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("RollbackTransaction"])
            {
                t.Session.Transaction.Rollback();
            }
            else
            {
                t.Session.Transaction.Commit();
            }
            t.Session.Dispose();
        });
```

Please note that `HttpContext` is thread local, that means when you switch threads it may be `null` or -worst case - it might even be another `HttpContext`.

Please also note that i was unable to try it out so it may not work. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: using HttpContext is quite dangerous: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12219078/656430, HttpContext.Current might become null in some situation.

Comment: True, especially with `async / await` this can become quite dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the state through HttpContext is not acceptable to me for 2 reasons.

1. HttpContext issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219078/656430)
2. Passing state seems like passing a global state (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

After a lot of trial and error, I think this should be one solution:
Assuming we are working on WebApi project, having rollback transaction for all actions once hit exception, with Ninject:

1. install **Ninject.Extension.Factory** (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/), this is very important step as to inject ISession in request scope into filters.
2. use the following configuration for binding `ISessionFactory` and `ISession` (I made use of this example: [Need a simple example of using nhibernate + unit of work + repository pattern + service layer + ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113245/need-a-simple-example-of-using-nhibernate-unit-of-work-repository-pattern)), plus *`ISessionInRequestScopeFactory`*

   ```
   Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider<NhibernateSessionFactoryProvider>().InSingletonScope();
   Bind<ISession>()
           .ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
           .InRequestScope(); // notice that we don't need to call `BeginTransaction` at this moment 
   Bind<ISessionInRequestScopeFactory>().ToFactory(); // you don't need to make your implementation, the Ninject.Extension.Factory extension will help you so.
   ```
3. the code for interface `ISessionInRequestScopeFactory`:

   ```
   public interface ISessionInRequestScopeFactory
   {
       ISession CreateSessionInRequestScope(); // return ISession in the request scope
   }
   ```
4. Make use of **ninject filter injection** to **add Transaction behaviour** to every action (https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-filters):

   ```
   Kernel.BindHttpFilter<ApiTransactionFilter>(System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterScope.Action)
       .WhenControllerHas<ApiTransactionAttribute>();
   ```
5. add `[ApiTransaction]` attribute into controller:

   ```
    [ApiTransaction]
    public class YourApiController{ /* ... */}
   ```
6. So we are now binding the `ApiTransactionFilter` into `YourApiController` which are having `[ApiTransaction]` Attribute
7. Inside `ApiTransactionFilter`, you should extends `AbstractActionFilter` and **inject the factory `ISessionInRequestScopeFactory` for getting the correct request scope session**:

   ```
   public class ApiTransactionFilter : AbstractActionFilter{
       private readonly ISessionInRequestScopeFactory factory;

       public ApiTransactionFilter(ISessionInRequestScopeFactory factory){
           this.factory = factory;
       }

       public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           ISession session = factory.CreateSessionInRequestScope(); // get the request scope session through factory
           session.BeginTransaction(); // session can begin transaction here ... 
           base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
       }

       public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
       {
           ISession session = factory.CreateSessionInRequestScope(); // get the request scope session through factory
           if (actionExecutedContext.Exception == null) // NO EXCEPTION!
           {
               session.Transaction.Commit();// session commit here ... may be you like to have try catch here
           }
           else
           {
              session.Transaction.Rollback(); // session rollback here ...
           }

           base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
       }
   }
   ```